# Send a string on Android with HttpPost without using nameValuePairs

Tags: android, string, http-post

I was looking information about how I can send information using HttpPost method on android, and I always see this:

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(posturl);

List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Name","Var1"));
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Name2","Var2"));

httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));    
HttpResponse resp = httpclient.execute(httppost);
HttpEntity ent = resp.getEntity();
```

The problem is that I cant do that, because I have to connect to a resource that receive a String with XML format.

Any idea about how can I send only the String without using a `List<nameValuePair>`

Comment: How did you get the idea that the above code is related to XML in any way? Plus, your string will need a name when you send it via http, so you'll end up with a name/value pair or a named URL parameter.

Comment: Ok please clarify what your _real_ problem is. Do you have an XML string and the server cannot accept an XML string value? Then you'll have to tell us what format(s) the server can accept. Or do you think that the name/value pair thingy has something to do with XML? Then the answer is, no, it doesn't. It just rids you of having to fill the `POST` body yourself.

Comment: Ok, The server use a javaScrip, on it he read a text you sent it and that text is a XML file or have that format. So i cant use the ValuePairs becasue i have to send only a String. but the methods i saw on internet only use a ValuePairs Array.

Now im trying to use Praful Bhatnagar answer. I think it will works

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. The core question is, how does the `POST` relate to the `JavaScript` snippet. You can request data in JavaScript, but can you receive a POST directy? I don't think so. This means that the server receives it before and passes it gets passed to the JavaScript through request variables, In this case, you're wasting your time with Praful's approach.

Comment: ok, i dont know why but his code work perfectly :) ty too Class.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Have you tried using [StringEntity](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/entity/StringEntity.html)? Above code can be updated to use `StringEntity`, Following is the resulting code:

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(posturl);


httppost.setEntity(new StringEntity("your string"));    
HttpResponse resp = httpclient.execute(httppost);
HttpEntity ent = resp.getEntity();
```

Comment: this method works for php function called file_get_contents('php://input')
only if we use $_POST['content'] this is not work.why is that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use JSON as post parameter. Try referring [FlexJson](http://flexjson.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: i cant use JSON, the server usea a JavaScript file

Answer (score -1):

```
// Sending HTTPs Requet to Server

    try {
        Log.v("GG", "Sending sever 1 - try");
        // start - line is for sever connection/communication
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(
                "10.0.0.1/abc.php");

        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("qrcode", contents));


        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(
                nameValuePairs));
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        // end - line is for sever connection/communication
        InputStream is = entity.getContent();

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Send to server and inserted into mysql Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();

        // Execute HTTP Post Request
        response= httpclient.execute(httppost);

        entity = response.getEntity();
        String getResult = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
        Log.e("response =", " " + getResult);



    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "
                + e.toString());
    }
```

Comment: This question was answered a long time ago, but your answer is not correct. You are using a list of NameValuePairs and i needed to send only a String without NameValuePairs.